# ASP.NET c# Checkboxlist in a template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I a newbie to asp.net. I have created a DB table in sqlserver with 3 columns; `ImageID, Filename & Score`.

FileName is `C:\pics\beads.png or C:\pics\moreimages\scenary.jpeg`.

Using C# asp.net, I have created a GridView. This Gridview should populate

(column 1)ImageID and get the image from the Filename (column2) and I have 2 Checkboxlist created as shown below which should accept score for the images from user and save it into the DB table.

**Question 1** .

I am able to populate Image ID, but Images are not getting populated.

**Question 2.**

I do not know how to access the `checkboxlist` since it is in template. The checked is in the default select and doesn't change even if I click on it. Which method/property should be used to do save the selection to the database. Here's my code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p style="height: 391px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Logos" Height="299px" Width="577px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageID" HeaderText="ImageID" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FileName" ControlStyle-Width="100"
                    ControlStyle-Height="100" HeaderText="Image" AlternateText="No image">
                    <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
                </asp:ImageField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Score" AccessibleHeaderText="CheckBoxList" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatColumns="3" ID="test">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="5">Good</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Not Good </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">OK</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>         

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Save" Width="130px" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="javaScript:window.close(); return false;" Text="Exit" Width="102px" />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </p>
</form>
```

---

```
public string sqlSel = @"SELECT TOP 3 [ImageID],FileName FROM [db1].[ImagesTest] where [Score] is null";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdSel = new SqlCommand(sqlSel, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader1 = cmdSel.ExecuteReader();
           
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                DataSet ds = GetData(sqlSel);

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();              
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Unable to connect to the database.");
                }

            }
            
        }
    
}

private DataSet GetData(string cmdSel)
{
   
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSel,con);
        sda.Fill(ds);
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("IN EXCEPTION "+ex.Message);
        return null;
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Thanks for ur time
Rashmi

Comment: Your Filename should have a URL in its value, like http://yoursite/pics/bead.png. On web something like C:\pics\beads.png will not render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, here is what it should be fixed:

**How to fix the images (Question 1)**

As @Guilherme said in the comments, for images use URLs instead of disk paths.
Replace the images disk paths `C:\pics\beads.png` or `C:\pics\moreimages\scenary.jpeg` to something like `Images/beads.png` and `Images/scenary.jpeg`.

For this to work, you will need to have a folder named `Images` that contains these two files on the same directory level as your `.aspx` file.

**Adjust your GridView1 declaration in the ASPX file**

On your GridView1 declaration you should:

1. attach a handler to the `OnRowDataBound` event. This will allow you to properly bind the `Score` dataset column to the `Score` gridview column
2. set the `DataKeyNames` property on the grid to what should be the primary key for your images table (in this case `DataKeyNames="ImageID"`)
3. use a `RadioButtonList` instead of a `CheckboxList`, because according to your dataset you can only set one value, which is what the `RadioButtonList` does. The `CheckboxList` is normally used when multiple selection is needed.
4. attach a handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the `RadioButtonList`. This will allow you to save the new values to the database (Question 2)

Here's how your GridView declaration should look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Logos" Height="299px" Width="577px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="ImageID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageID" HeaderText="ImageID" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FileName" ControlStyle-Width="100"
                ControlStyle-Height="100" HeaderText="Image" AlternateText="No image">
                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Score" AccessibleHeaderText="RadioButtonList" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatColumns="3" ID="test" OnSelectedIndexChanged="test_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Good</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Not Good </asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">OK</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

                    <!-- UPDATED! - keep the old values in a hidden field -->
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfOldScore" Value='<%# Eval("Score") %>' />                    
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Adjust your code behind value in your .ASPX.CS file (Question 2)**

On the code behind, you will also need to:

1. Make sure you are binding to the GridView only once in the `Page_Load` event, by checking the `IsPostBack` property
2. (Optional, but recommended) Move the logic of getting data (with the SQLConnection code) in a separate method that will handle only data retrieval
3. Implement the handler for the `OnRowDataBound` event. This will bind any values from the `Score` column to the `RadioButtonList` control
4. Implement the handler for the `SelectedIndexChecked` event of the `RadioButtonList` control. This will allow you to save to the database the new values

Finally, here's the entire code-behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)        
    {
        //bind only the first time the page loads
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {                
            DataSet ds = GetData(sqlSel);

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Unable to connect to the database.");
            }
        }
    }

    private DataSet GetData(string cmdSel)
    {
        //normally you should query the data from the DB
        //I've manually constructed a DataSet for simplification purposes
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ImageID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FileName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Score", typeof(int)));

        dt.Rows.Add(100, @"Images/beads.png", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add(200, @"Images/moreimages/scenary.jpeg", 3);
        dt.Rows.Add(300, @"Images/moreimages/scenary.jpeg", 5);


        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        return ds;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //UPDATED - iterate through all the data rows and build a dictionary of items
        //to be saved
        Dictionary<int, int> dataToUpdate = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int imageID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
                int oldScore;
                int newScore; 

                int.TryParse((row.FindControl("hfOldScore") as HiddenField).Value, out oldScore);
                int.TryParse((row.FindControl("test") as RadioButtonList).SelectedValue, out newScore);

                if (oldScore != newScore)
                {
                    dataToUpdate.Add(imageID, newScore);
                }
            }
        }

        //update only the images that were changed
        foreach (var keyValuePair in dataToUpdate)
        {
            SaveToDB(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //we are only interested in the data Rows
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row;
            //manually bind the Score column to the RadioButtonlist
            int? scoreId = dataRow["Score"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null : (int)dataRow["Score"];
            if (scoreId.HasValue)
            {
                RadioButtonList test = e.Row.FindControl("test") as RadioButtonList;
                test.ClearSelection();                    
                test.SelectedValue = scoreId.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void test_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList test = sender as RadioButtonList;
        GridViewRow gridRow = test.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        //obtain the current image Id
        int imageId = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gridRow.RowIndex].Value;

        //obtain the current selection (we will take the first selected checkbox
        int selectedValue = int.Parse(test.SelectedValue);

        //UPDATED! - saves are now handled on the Save button click
        //SaveToDB(imageId, selectedValue);

    }

    private void SaveToDB(int imageId, int score)
    {
        //UPDATED!
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@ImageID", imageId);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Score", score);
                command.CommandText = @"update [db1].[ImagesTest] set Score = @Score where [ImageID] = @ImageID";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

**UPDATED!**

- The declaration of the `GridView1` now contains a hidden field containing the Score value. You can use this hidden field to determine which row has changed, so you can trigger a save only on the changed ones
- Save is now done on the click of the Save button, by iterating through the rows of the grid an building a `Dictionary<int,string>` to keep only the changes.
- `SaveToDB` method should work, but I cannot test this myself.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Lucian. I was trying to save to DB only after "Save button is clicked. Do I need to save values in array and then save it. Is there any other method that is better than this.

Comment: Depending on the number of rows that need to be saved you can save the items sequentially one image at a time or save in a batch. The first one is pretty straightforward: you iterate through the rows of the gridview obtaining the ImageID and the Score values and then save each row independently. The second way is more complex: you must gather all the grid data in a DataSet object, and then save the entire thing in a batch update with a SQL Stored Procedure. Unless you are really sure that there's a ton of data to be saved, I would recommend you to go with the first version.

Comment: #1 option, we can't do. in SelectedIndexchanged, I have Datacolumn d1=new DataColumn("ImageID");dt.Columns.Add(d1); dt.Rows.Add(d1)..did this for other columns. In save buttonclick-> after declaring connection object,adap.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ImagesTest set Score=@Score,DateNow=@datenow where ImageID=@imageID",con);
        adap.Fill(dt);
        adap.Update(dt);
        con.Close(); I get null pointer exception.

Comment: I've updated my solution based on your comments. I did not get what you mean on the SelectedIndexChanged (btw, this is not needed anymore since the saving is handled on the Save button).

Comment: wow!!I have a sharp learning curve here. Thanks for your time Lucian

Comment: You are welcome. Once you've resolved your problem please mark the answer as the accepted solution (if you feel so :) )

Answer (score 1):

**Question 2**:
To access your checkbox you can use.

```
 GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
 CheckBox Ckbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

> For Question 1

Instead of ImageField you can use use ASP:Image in Templatefield like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Score" AccessibleHeaderText="CheckBoxList" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ID="imageControl" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Filename") %>'></asp:Image>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

> For Question 2

This is one of the example for how to access each Checkbox list inside gridview

```
    For Each gvr As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
        If (CType(gvr.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)).Checked = True Then
            ReDim uPrimaryid(iCount)
            uPrimaryid(iCount) = New Integer
            uPrimaryid(iCount) = gvr.Cells("uPrimaryID").Text
            iCount += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks!! I have used Vignesh Kumar (quest1) & Lucian's code (question2) to get it working.  Here's a catch though. The images are displayed in IE but not in Chrome. I do not understand why. I cannot upvote b'coz i am a new member.